# Show that $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are linearly dependent on the interval $-\infty < t < \infty$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ be solutions of $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+p(t)\frac{dy}{dt}+q(t)y=0$ on the interval $-\infty < t < \infty$ with:
$y_1(0)=3$, $y_1'(0)=1$, $y_2(0)=1$, $y_2'(0)=1/3$. Show that $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are linearly dependent on the interval $-\infty < t < \infty$.

My attempt:

So to be linear dependent means to have a Wronskian =0 I think.

$W(t)=W[y_1,y_2](t)=y_1(t)y_2'(t)-y_1'(t)y_2(t)$

And I am given:
$$y_1(0)=3$$ $$y_1'(0)=1$$ $$y_2(0)=1$$ $$y_2'(0)=1/3$$

So $W(t)=W[y_1,y_2](t)=3*1/3-1*1=1-1=0$

Is that really all there is to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right (assuming that $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are continuous functions). Another way to think about it which may be more intuitive is to notice that both initial conditions for $y_1$ are just 3 times those for $y_2$. This means that $y_1$ and $3y_2$ both satisfy the same initial conditions, namely:
$$y_1(0)=3y_2(0)=3, y_1'(0)=(3y_2)'(0)=1$$
Since $y_1$ and $3y_2$ are both solutions to the ODE satisfying the same initial conditions, a uniqueness theorem says that they must actually be the same function, i.e. $y_1=3y_2$. In other words, $y_1$ is just a scalar multiple of $y_2$, which means they are linearly dependent.